# How to split a text file on c#

Tags: c#

I have to split a .txt file in many .txt file in a different directory.

For example: the first word of my text file is "Dipendent" when I reach the next "dipendent" I have to cut the file and make a copy of that portion of text in another .txt file in a different directory.

So I need to create a .txt file that go from the first word "dipendent" to the next "dipendent" (in my file there are about 50 "dipendent" and I have to create a .txt file for each portion of text).

Comment: Have you tried to code it yourself? What's the problem? Opening file? Parsing file? Creating new file?

Comment: Yes i tried but i had problem in parsing the file

Comment: Why didn't you make a question about **that**, instead, then? As it currently stands this isn't a question - it's a document of requirements with no visible effort at solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont make a habbit of asking ppl to write your code,
but, in order to welcome you to the community:
(you should make the code safer openning and closing the files.)

```
    public void Texts(FileInfo srcFile, DirectoryInfo outDir, string splitter = "dipendent")
    {
        // open file reader
        using (StreamReader srcRdr = new StreamReader(srcFile.FullName))
        {
            int outFileIdx = 1;
            StreamWriter outWriter = new StreamWriter(outDir.FullName + srcFile.Name + outFileIdx + ".txt");

            while (!srcRdr.EndOfStream)  //  read lines one by one untill ends
            {
                string readLine = srcRdr.ReadLine();
                int indexOfSplitter = readLine.IndexOf(splitter, StringComparison.Ordinal); // find splitter
                if(indexOfSplitter >= 0) // if there is a splitter
                {
                    outWriter.WriteLine(readLine.Substring(indexOfSplitter)); // write whats before...

                    //outWriter.WriteLine(readLine.Substring(indexOfSplitter) + splitter.Length); // use if you want splitting text to apear in the end of the previous file

                    outWriter.Close(); // close the current file
                    outWriter.Dispose();

                    // update the Text to be written to exclude what's already written to the current fils
                    readLine = readLine.Substring(indexOfSplitter); 
                    //readLine = readLine.Substring(indexOfSplitter + splitter.Length);  // Use if you want splitting text to apear in the new file

                    // OPEN NEXT FILE
                    outFileIdx++; 
                    outWriter = new StreamWriter(outDir.FullName + srcFile.Name + outFileIdx + ".txt");
                }
                outWriter.WriteLine(readLine);
            }

            outWriter.Close();
            outWriter.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
Regex.Split(myString,"Dipendent")
```

or

```
myString.Split(new [] {"Dipendent"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

you could also take a look at  `String.Substring(Startindex, length)`

Edit: should have refreshed my page - wudzik is right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method which uses efficient string methods:

```
public static List<string> GetParts(string text, string token, StringComparison comparison, bool inclToken)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    int index = text.IndexOf(token, comparison);
    while (index > -1)
    {
        index += token.Length;
        int endIndex = text.IndexOf(token, index, comparison);
        if (endIndex == -1)
        {
            string item = String.Format("{0}{1}", inclToken ? token : "", text.Substring(index));
            items.Add(item);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string item = String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", inclToken ? token : "", text.Substring(index, endIndex - index));
            items.Add(item);
        }
        index = text.IndexOf(token, endIndex, comparison);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Then use it in this way:

```
var fileText = File.ReadAllText(oldPath);
var items = GetParts(fileText, "Dipendent", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, true);
```

Now you have all parts and you can generate new files for each part.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    var fileName = string.Format("Dipendent_{0}.txt", i + 1);
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, fileName);
    File.WriteAllText(fullPath, items[i]);
}
```